# How do I make one side of a polymorphic join table unique when I create new records through a has_many association with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I have four models Skill, Project, Endorsement, and Profile. There are a set list of skills that need to be able to be expanded over time, all unique; I want to create a join table that attaches to Project, Endorsement, and Profile.

## Models

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :skill_joins, as: :target
  has_many :skills, through: :skill_joins
end

class Endorsement < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :skill_joins, as: :target
  has_many :skills, through: :skill_joins
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :skill_joins, as: :target
  has_many :skills, through: :skill_joins
end

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :target, polymorphic: true, optional: true
  has_many :skill_joins

  validates :skill_name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end

class SkillJoin < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :target, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

## Migration for Skill Join

```
  create_table "skill_joins", id: :uuid, default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.uuid "skill_id", null: false
    t.uuid "target_id", null: false
    t.string "target_type", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["target_id", "target_type"], name: "index_skill_joins_on_target_id_and_target_type"
  end
```

I'm running into the problem where I call `Profile.second.skills.find_or_create_by(skill_name: "something")` and it creates the skill and the join but when I call `Profile.third.skills.find_or_create_by(skill_name: "something")` it loads the skill but won't create the join but rollsback as it tried to create the skill again.

If I have Skill records of "Javascript", "Java", and "Ruby" and I call `Profile.third.skills.find_or_create_by(skill_name: "Ruby")`, how do I not create two "Ruby" skills but link to the existing one?

All four models use UUIDs.

Answer (score 1):

You could do `Profile.third.skills << Skill.find_or_create_by(skill_name: "Ruby")`.  With rails "magic" it will automatically create the join record when you use the the shovel operator.